# Issue with calender object ,showing 30min difference when added one day minutes to the current date?

Tags: java, calendar

Basically am trying to add some x minutes to some y date,

```
    Calendar startDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDateCal.setTime(selectedDates.getStartDate());
    System.out.println("before adding"+startDateCal.getTime());


    startDateCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) adjustTimeValue);
    System.out.println("After addindg"+startDateCal.getTime());
```

Output was

```
   before addingSat Apr 08 10:31:29 IST 2017
   After addindgSun Apr 09 10:00:29 IST 2017
```

I got adjustTimeValue as 1440 minutes so the output should be below one right ? after adding 1440 minutes

```
  After addindgSun Apr 09 10:31:29 IST 2017
```

Where is the problem why am getting 30 min less output  after adding total one days minutes?

sometimes getting 39min also, so basically these extra minutes are not getting showed up.

Comment: `startDateCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE` ... you didn't add anything, you set the minute value to `1440`, so I'm assuming there's some internal rolling going on that doesn't quite equate to a full 24 hours - Now, if you can, make use Java 8's new Time API instead

Comment: Java8 shouldn't be used in our project,but could you please tell where exactly am doing mistake

Comment: Change `Calendar.set` to `Calendar.add`

Comment: And don't add 1 day worth of minutes, add one day. One day is not always the same amount of minutes; there may be daylight savings times, changes to time zones, clock corrections, leap seconds, etc. Use the API that allows you at add 1 day instead.

Comment: @madProgrammer Thank u so much , i got :) Am new to date API,So  confused little...

Comment: @Erwin thanks for suggestion, that am following actually, i get "adjustTimeValue" in the question dynamically can be any minutes, but right now i got one day equivalent minutes, So i mentioned one day in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `startDateCal.add()` instead of `startDateCal.set()`. The set just updates the value of that field (in your case, the minute) and will ignore the previous value.